# How do I add support for browser features like WebGL to TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

```
var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('canvas1');
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 400;
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
```

The "HTMLCanvasElement" only seems to offer 2d canvas methods. It won't let me compile gl.viewport() etc. How do I add this support for WebGL?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to define WebGL methods before you use them. You can find some community written WebGL typing [here](https://github.com/piersh/WebGL.ts/blob/master/WebGL.d.ts). Add the WebGL.d.ts to your project and call it like:

```
///<reference path="WebGL.d.ts" />

var canvas = <any>document.getElementById('canvas1');
var gl =  <WebGLRenderingContext> canvas.getContext('webgl');
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 400;
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. By the way, I'm embarassed to say that this is actually explained in the language specification right at the start, I usually just skim these things but it's called "Ambient Declarations" in Typescript.